# terminal - having "$" instead of MyComputer:~ me$

Tags: bash, terminal, osx, prompt

Right now in my MacOS X terminal I have `MyComputer:~ me$` before all the commands.

In some videos I saw they have just `$` - that's much less clutter, how is it done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This text is printed by your [shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/shell/info), and it's called a [prompt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt).

Your shell is probably [bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/bash/info). The prompt is set in bash's initialisation file, which is `.bashrc` in your home directory. Specifically, the prompt is set by the `PS1` variable. Its value can contain [escape sequences](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Printing-a-Prompt.html) that are replaced by some value when the prompt is displayed. For example, `MyComputer:~ me$` results from a prompt setting like

```
PS1='\h:\w \u\$ '  # host name colon working directory space user name dollar space
```

Try adding the following line at the end of your `.bashrc` (create it if it doesn't exist):

```
PS1='\$ '
```

---

If this doesn't change anything, it's because you have a login shell and no proper `.bash_profile`. See [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile) for an explanation. Short story: create a `.bash_profile` containing

```
if [ -r ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi
case "$-" in *i*) if [ -r ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi;; esac
```